# Checking Whether the Points $(x, y, w)^T = (1, \pm i, 0)^T$ Lie in the Circle $(x - aw)^2 + (y - bw)^2 = r^2 w^2$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, projective-geometry

Page 5 of my computer vision textbook, *Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision*, says the following:

> The equation for a circle in homogeneous coordinates $(x, y, w)$ is of the form
>
> $$(x - aw)^2 + (y - bw)^2 = r^2 w^2$$
>
> This represents the circle with centre represented in homogeneous coordinates as $(x_0, y_0, w_0)^T = (a, b, 1)^T$. It is quickly verified that the points $(x, y, w)^T = (1, \pm i, 0)^T$ lie on every such circle.

The aforementioned section of the textbook is available freely [here](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/hzbook/hzbook2/HZintroduction.pdf).

Now, as I understand it, I can verify that the points lie in the circle by using the Euclidean distance:

$$d(x, y, w) = \sqrt{(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2 + (w - w_0)^2}$$

However, if I plug in the provided values, then it seems that we would end up with the following two messy expressions:

$$d(1, i, 0) = \sqrt{(1 - a)^2 + (i - b)^2 + 1} \tag{1}$$

$$d(1, -i, 0) = \sqrt{(1 - a)^2 + (-i - b)^2 + 1} \tag{2}$$

It is not clear to me how/whether this tells us that the points lie in the circle?

So how does one verify that the points lie on every such circle? The author states that this is "quickly verifiable".

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: When you say the you "plug in the values into the equation for the circle in homogeneous coordinates", are you plugging $x$ in for $aw$ and $y$ in for $bw$?  Maybe you could give some more detail on what exactly you did at this step.

Comment: @gd1035 I made an oversight. Will change question now.

Comment: What do you mean by the Euclidean distance between an imaginary point (either of the circular points) and a real one (the circle’s center)?

Comment: Distance isn’t meaningful in projective geometry in the first place, let alone the distance between a real and imaginary point. Trying to verify that those points lie on any circle by trying to compute distances was the wrong approach.

Comment: One of the main points of that section is that you _impose_ an Euclidean geometry on the projective plane by choosing a pair of points to serve as the circular points. All non-degenerate conics are projectively equivalent, so you can only distinguish between ellipses, parabolas and hyperbolas by choosing a line to be the line at infinity. Similarly, distinguishing circles from ellipses requires imposing a Euclidean geometry on the plane: circles are then those ellipses that pass through the two distinguished points.

Comment: @amd Ahh, yes, this makes sense. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plug $x=1$, $y=\pm i$ amd $w=0$ into the equation, to get:
$$
(1-0)^2+(\pm i-0)^2 = 0,
$$
which is obviously always true.

Comment: Ahh, I’m not sure if you saw the post before the edit, but this is the direction I was going with. But how does one interpret this? *What* is always true?

Comment: It's true that those points obey the equation, and then by definition lie on the circle represented by that equation.

Comment: So if the points obey the equation, then they must, by definition, be part of the circle?

Comment: It depends on how you define a circle, but whether by definition or not they do lie on the circle.

Comment: okay, thanks for the clarification.